# Bootstrap 3.0 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

With the code below is as close as I can get, I just can't get the right hand side bar to be alignment with the top edge of the left hand top box. Being new to Bootstrap I just can't get it to work.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="lh-top col-md-8 col-sm-9">left hand top area</div>           
  <div class="lh-dip-lower col-md-8 col-sm-9">left hand lower</div>           
  <div class="rh-dip col-sm-4 col-sm-3">Right hand side bar</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you've laid this out, you've defined three columns in a single row. Since your grid-column counts exceed 12, they will wrap to the next line. So for example, at "md" sizes, the left hand top area will render on the first row; then since the next column (left hand lower) would cause it to exceed 12 grid columns, it and the following column (right hand side bar) wrap to the following row.

I think you want something more like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="lh-column" col-md-8 col-sm-9></div>
<div id="rh-column" col-md-4 col-sm-3></div>
</div>
```

You can then create columns within the left-hand and right-hand columns by embedding other Bootstrap columns like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="lh-column" col-md-8 col-sm-9>
      <div class="lh-top col-md-8 col-sm-9">left hand top area</div>           
      <div class="lh-dip-lower col-md-8 col-sm-9">left hand lower</div>
</div>
<div id="rh-column" col-md-4 col-sm-3>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, when I tried the above, the right hand column wraps under the "lh-dip-lower col-md-8 col-sm-9" rather than a column going up & down on the right hand side.

Comment: Yes, copy and paste got away from me. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can just divide up the row between left and right content div. Within the left parent div you can add your top and left content area, which will be automatically 100% of its parent. This ensures that your right hand side bar is top aligned with the left hand content div.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="lh-column" class="col-md-8 col-sm-9">
    <div class="lh-top">left hand top area</div>           
    <div class="lh-dip-lower">left hand lower</div>
  </div>
  <div id="rh-column" class="col-md-4 col-sm-3"></div>
</div><!-- End .row -->
```

Comment: Fantastic!! That's excatly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Also was intending to say thank you but I hit the enter key a little early lol Thank you Charles

Comment: Cheers! Please consider marking my answer as the correct one if it solved your problem. :)